# Remove an element from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to remove an element of the array based on a match.
Here is my method to remove the event.

```
public boolean removeEvent(int year, int month, int day, int start, int end, String activity)
    {
    Event newEvent = new Event(year, month, day, start, end, activity);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {   
        if (newEvent.equals(events[i]))
        {
            events[i] = null;
            newEvent = null;
            numEvents--;
        }
    }
```

When I try

```
calendarTest1.removeEvent(2000, 1, 1, 1, 1, "Cal Test 1");
```

nothing happens. I have an element in my array with those values but it does not change that element to null.

This is for homework so I don't really want to be told how to do it, just why this does not work. Thank you.

Here is my equals method:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){

    Event someEvent = (Event) obj;
        if(
        this.date == someEvent.date
            &&
        this.start == someEvent.start
            &&
        this.end == someEvent.end
            &&
        this.activity.equals(someEvent.activity))

    if(obj == null) 
        return false;
      if(obj instanceof Event)
        return true;
      else
      {
      return false;
      }
}
```

I have tried a lot of different things but I still get the NullPointerException Error

Comment: Looks like the `equals` method in your `Event` class is broken. Post its implementation to get further help.

Comment: Can you post the overridden `equals()` function for Event?

Comment: Perhaps your array is longer than 5? Trying using a variable that is the length of your array. In addition, are `events` and `numEvents` in scope?

Comment: Make sure your equals is checking for all the attributes to be equal and returning true if they are.

Comment: Haven't seen the implementation of your `equals` method but I can only think the problem is you're comparing `String activity` using `==` instead of `equals` or sending the wrong data to remove the element from your array.

Answer (score 0):

is your equals method checking for all the attributes?

```
public boolean equals(Object o){
  if(o == null) return false;

  if(o instanceOf Event){
    Event givenObject = (Event) o;
        if(this.year == givenObject.year)
          if(this.month == givenObject.month)
              .....
                  .....
                     if(this.activity.equals(givenObject.activity)){
                        return true;
                 }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: There's no `bool` data type in Java.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.activity.equals(givenObject.activity)` based on his parameters?

Comment: @Jordan Did that in hurry. I hope it was not misunderstood since had to compare Strings.

Comment: By the way, you're not overriding the `equals` method but overloading it.

Comment: @JHL naw, made sense to me, just thought I would point it out. (Not sure you deserve whoever gave you the -1 :/ )

Comment: @Jordan that was me to caught person's attention on fix the answer. And one more error: there's no `givenObject` variable in the current `equals` method.

Comment: @Jordan Thats fine. If its not upvoted it means its not the best one, so have a chance for downvote, provided given valid reasons. :)

Comment: I think using && between conditions instead of nesting them is better. I try to stay away from deep nesting.

Answer (score 0):

your overridden equal method shoud be somethig like below

```
   @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {

            // If the object is compared with itself then return true  
            if (o == this) {
                return true;
            }

            /* Check if o is an instance of Event or not
              "null instanceof [type]" also returns false */
            if (!(o instanceof Event)) {
                return false;
            }

            // typecast o to Event so that we can compare data members 
            Event e = (Event) o;

            // Compare the data members and return accordingly 
            return year==e.year && month== e.month && day==e.day && start == e.start && end == e.end && activity.equals(e.activity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `activity == e.activity` **this is not they way you compare `String`s**: http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1065197

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing two instances in this if `event[i]` has `Event` instance then comparison way is different then strings comparison.

You need to override `equals` method in you class ex:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object ob) {
    if (ob == null)
        return false;
    if (ob instanceof Event) {
         Event e = (Event)ob;
         return this.someStringValue.equals(e.someStringValueItHas); // compare all values you want like this
    }
        return false;
}
```

here we check correct instance of class then its properties if they are equal or not.